# Does the JSTL <c:out> tag handle an EL arithmetic operation or just spit out String?

Tags: jstl, el

I have an EL expression ${4+(param.a)*4} in a jsp.

Will changing it to the following line of code do the arithmetic operation first then spit out the result as string or evaluate the whole expression as string first?

```
<c:out value='${4+(param.a)*4}'/>
```

I want to do the arithmetic operation 1st and then output the result as string.

Answer (score 0):

Arithmetic operation first and gives you the result which will be printed in html element.

Comment: what if the value for param.a is "<script>alert("test")</script>?

Comment: Jps works on top of JVM, java is strick type. So if your variable "param.a" is of type string you may get compile time exception.